# Print does not work when I run it after using driver.find_elements_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get some information from a page and I am having some problems when I try to print the data. I am relatively new in Python and also in HTML/Javascript.

The page I want to **scrape** is dynamic, so as I scroll down, new code appears (maybe its important for my problem).

The text I want to get it’s “SKU:  9165221”

[image]

And this is my code for that part:

```
skus = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1bnfI1NVgLYTTy9EpaXGRA _3aVhOQmbPfemOgw8Ihvm5g")
for product in skus:
    print(product.text)
```

When I run the print, there are no errors, but nothing appears below the print, nothing. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpUlF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this line `print(len(skus))`, then you get a return value of `0`, it's causes your code never goes into looping.

It seems like your element having more than one class name, you can't use `.find_elements_by_class_name`, that's only for single class name. Instead you can use `.find_elements_by_css_selector`.

**#UPDATE**

With `WebDriverWait`:

```
skus = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._1bnfI1NVgLYTTy9EpaXGRA._3aVhOQmbPfemOgw8Ihvm5g')))
print(len(skus))
for product in skus:
    print(product.text)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I got the print(len(skus))= 14 but the last print didn't work. It just stays there showing nothing (image attached) Do you have any other idea what may be causing this? Thank you so much again, I am kind of desperate to get this because I need that for my business stock management.

Comment: @SharifHamed may you need `WebDriverWait` to solve it, please see the above updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but unfortunately the problem persists... Nothing appears after I run the print(product.text). May the website be protected or something?

Comment: @SharifHamed is possible to share the web url?

Comment: It's marketplace and I am a seller in it. The url just goes to the log in page, I would have to share my credentials for you to see the page and my orders ☹

Comment: @SharifHamed if related with login credential, please don't share here. Maybe you can share HTML structure?

Comment: Done! Sorry I forgot to do it earlier. Thank you so much again. Best regards!